# Is it necessary to recreate a Google-managed SSL certificate when switching the SSL resolution to a different provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, ssl-certificate-errors

I attempted to migrate a website from GCP to AWS Lightsail and then back again in order to gain a better understanding of the process. However, I discovered that the process was not as straightforward than I initially thought.

**Steps I followed for migrating to AWS:**

1. I set up an AWS Lightsail instance.
2. I directed the A record to point to the AWS Lightsail instance.
3. I installed a Letsencrypt SSL certificate at the server level.

**Steps I followed for migrating back to GCP:**

1. I restarted the GCP VM (I retained the source VM on GCP without deletion).
2. I checked that the Google-managed SSL certificate remained active.
3. I redirected the A record to point back to the GCP VM.
4. I stopped the AWS Lightsail instance.
5. However, the website failed to load due to an invalid SSL certificate.
6. I verified with an SSL checker, and it correctly resolved to the GCP VM.
7. I deleted the Google managed SSL and recreate it

Is it necessary to recreate a Google-managed SSL certificate when switching the SSL resolution to a different provider?

From my personal experience(not much though), the downtime involved in using Google managed SSL certificate is quite significant. Once you've used it, it appears to adopt a "vendor-locked" framework.

Comment: I think you need to learn how to dig a bit further than "invalid SSL certificate".

Comment: @symcbean thanks. do you mind to elaborate?

Comment: What is reporting it is invalid? Why is it invalid?

Comment: thanks @symcbean The SSL correctly resolves to the GCP VM but it states the ssl certificate has expired 285 days ago. I have no idea what comes up to this date.